# How to upgrade vmware esx 3.0.2 to 3.0.3

Tags: vmware-esx

i'd like to know how I can upgrade vmware ESX 3.0.2 to 3.0.3 - where to get the patches?
On vmware's website I can only find the 3.0.3 update 1 patch, which requires a ESX 3.0.3.

It's EOL is reached - but it must be possible to still retrieve the 3.0.3 patch files?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Got any extra/similar hardware lying around? We usually step things over, in place upgrades usually just cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

It's end-of-life'd as far as I'm aware.

Comment: yes - but isn't it possible to get the 'old' (we're talking about 2,5 years) patches in some more or less official way?

Comment: @MRalwasser: I'm not sure I'd trust installing more-or-less-official-patches on my hosts...

Comment: Sorry but as you'll see on their own site they no longer have any patches available for 3.0.2 including the 3.0.2-to-3.0.3 update - sorry.