# Vmware ESX 3.0.2 - vm guests are hanging constantly

Tags: linux, vmware-esx

I've got the problem that the vms of my vmware esx 3.0.2 server are hanging constantly (let's say every 3-5 minutes) for about 5-8 seconds. 
How can I track this issue down and get rid of it?

Thank you!

Comment: Upgrade to a supported version and call vmware perhaps?

Comment: "Upgrade to a supported version". That's another problem. See http://serverfault.com/questions/200818/how-to-upgrade-vmware-esx-3-0-2-to-3-0-3 for details

Comment: Ditto above. You're a long way behind! If you decide to go V4.1, remember vCenter is now x64 only.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /var/log/vmkernel.log for anything suspicious or that repeats constantly.  If all the VMs are running on the same VMFS volume you may be having intermittent (recoverable) storage failures, those would show up in the VMkernel logs.

Answer (score 0):

what's hanging exactly? I recently had the problem that /dev/random was empty, and apache was hanging on incoming SSL connections.